# How can I determine if something is an array or an object in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, object

What is the best way to determine if something is an array or an object in PHP?  I get a response from a web service and it's either an array or an object depending on how many returned results there are.  It is impossible to predict ahead of time how many there will be, so I need to figure out how to process it appropriately.  What is the best way to do this?

TIA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[is_array](https://www.php.net/is_array)

Comment: Well played.  JFGI fail on my part.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the [`is_object`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php) and [`is_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) PHP functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
is_array ($var)
```

Answer (score 1):

[is_array()](https://www.php.net/is%5Farray)and [is_object()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php)